# How to override a property so it returns a different value if the property is empty?

Tags: ember.js

I am probably going to use an ArrayController + itemController setup to solve this, but maybe this is better off inside the model layer.

I want to override the property of an object to return another value if the property is empty. I think this i best described in code (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahx_/Tqw4C/2/).

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Teacher = Ember.Object.extend()

App.Pupil = Ember.Object.extend({
  // TODO Add a property ('answer') that returns teacher.answer unless this.answer is defined
  // Pseudo-code:
  // answer: function(key, value) {
  //  if(Ember.isEmpty(this.answer)) {
  //   return this.get('teacher.answer')
  //  } else {
  //   return this.answer
  //  }
  // }.property('answer')
})

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super()
    teacher = App.Teacher.create({answer: 'correct'})
    this.set('pupil1', App.Pupil.create({ teacher: teacher, answer: 'incorrect' }))
    this.set('pupil2', App.Pupil.create({ teacher: teacher }))
  }
})
```

Comment: Your best bet might be to just define a computed property with a different name. I think a Handlebars helper for defining fallback default static text in the case of null values would be nice though. That wouldn't really work in your case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another property as `.property()` cannot refer to itself.

**Object:**

```
App.Pupil = Ember.Object.extend({
  answerToShow: function(){
    return this.get('answer') ? this.get('answer') : this.get('teacher.answer')
  }.property('answer')
})
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  Pupil1 ('incorrect'): {{pupil1.answerToShow}}
  <br>
  Pupil2 ('correct'): {{pupil2.answerToShow}}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tqw4C/5/